# Match from different data sets in R

Tags: r, match, lookup

I have currently 3 csv files namely `df`, `mf`, `cf`

`df` has one column with `A, B, C, D, E, F`

`mf` has two columns with `A, B, C` in the first and `US, India, China` in the second column

`cf` has two columns with `D, E, F` in the first and `Uruguay, Argentina, Brazil` in the second column

Looking for a vlookup type function wherein I want to lookup the data from `mf` and `cf` into file `df`. So the function should first look into `mf` and plot the details in second column of `df` then if not found it should move to `cf` for the finding missing in `df`... Please note the output should in second column of `df`

The above is a simplified example... have to lookup from multiple files hence would be helpful if this can be done in R.

Comment: `match()` (just like your question title!) if you want to do it on the fly for individual columns , `merge()` if you want to combine the data into a single data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `match` function (as @Gregor also suggested) in two steps with *data.table* where you only match for the `NA` rows the second time:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, country := mf$y[match(x, mf$x)]
          ][is.na(country), country := cf$z[match(x, cf$x)]]
```

---

Used data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))
mf <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C"), y = c("US", "India", "China"))
cf <- data.frame(x = c("D", "E", "F"), z = c("Uruguay", "Argentina", "Brazil"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hers's a possible approach :

```
df <- data.frame(Id=c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mf <- data.frame(Id=c('A','B','C'),Country=c('US', 'India', 'China'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
cf <- data.frame(Id=c('D','E','F'),Country=c('Uruguay', 'Argentina', 'Brazil'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ef <- data.frame(Id=c('A','G'),Country=c('XXX', 'Italy'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

otherDFs <- list(mf,cf,ef)
df$Country <- NA # initialize df$Country column to NA
for(other in otherDFs){
  matchingIds <- match(df$Id,other$Id)
  matchingIds[!is.na(df$Country)] <- NA

  countries <- other$Country[matchingIds]
  df$Country <- ifelse(is.na(countries),df$Country,countries)
}

> df
  Id   Country
1  A        US
2  B     India
3  C     China
4  D   Uruguay
5  E Argentina
6  F    Brazil
7  G     Italy
```

Note that I've added another data.frame `ef` which re-defines `A` as `XXX` instead of `US`. But with the described approach the initially matched value of `A` (i.e. `US`) is not replaced.

Comment: The package suggested by Jaap helped...but thanks for suggesting the method to do it without the package..